# How to find customer purchased from which store?

Tags: magento, store

I have 2 stores under a single magento named as aaaaaa and bbbbbb. Store ID's are 1 and 2.

```
     Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

I know this line of code is used to get current store id.

```
   $orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
```

This is for get all order details.From this $orderCollection, how to get customer details who have purchased only from store_id=2

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi please help me..it is possible to generate different order id's for different stores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this : `$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', 2)`

Comment: hi please help me..it is possible to generate different order id's for different stores